# How to add User Secrets programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I would like to create [User Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows) from a .NET Core Application without using the **dotnet** executable.
Is there a standard way to do it?